# Resources on exterior algebra, wedge product, geometric product and tensors

Tags: abstract-algebra, tensors, online-resources

I would like to learn exterior algebra, wedge product and geometric product along with their applications in physics. Is there a good source you can recommend? Should I study **differential geometry** in order to grasp them? I started studying tensor analysis but even the concept of contravariance and covariance is not explained well enough in most of the textbooks. I would be grateful if you point at a source that guides one well and assumes no prior knowledge of the topics except calculus and linear algebra.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Personally, when I came to the subject of exterior algebra I found no better a text than R.W.R Darling's *Differential Forms and Connections*: see [link here](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0521468000)

Comment: Thanks for the recommendation do you think it is suitable for self study? I do not want to have problems that are too hard to solve for someone novice in the field.

Comment: I had working knowledge of Differential Geometry and Riemannian Geometry when I began self-studying the book in my first graduate year. I don't think you will see a huge jump; you may even try Nakahara's Geometry, Toplogy & Physics too - see http://www.amazon.co.uk/Geometry-Topology-Physics-Edition-Graduate/dp/0750306068

Comment: Thanks, the fact is I do not have a working knowledge of differential geometry right now and I am going to self-study.

Comment: Well that's ok, take the plunge. If you feel you may need further knowledge in Differential Geometry try John McCleary's Geometry from a Differentiable Viewpoint or Differential Geometry by Kreyszig.